# How to count across all levels in PIVOT query?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

How can I calculate count for all the levels in PIVOT query? E.g. this counts across ename and job, but how to calculate count for all job levels, not just for CLERK, SALESMAN and MANAGER?

```
with pivot_data as (
  select ename, job
  from scott.emp
)
select * from pivot_data
pivot (count(*) for job in('CLERK', 'SALESMAN', 'MANAGER'));
```

Comment: I found from [here](http://www.eeblog.org/index.php/pivot-table-generic-sql-query-and-oracle-database-11g-pivot-operator/) that "This PIVOT operator has a big limitation: the arguments of the IN clause cannot be passed dinamically." Too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include all jobs without listing them explicitly in the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT`, besides dynamic sql, you can use `PIVOT XML` and rewrite the query as follows:

```
-- sample of data
with t1(col) as(
  select 'CLERK'    from dual union all
  select 'SALESMAN' from dual union all
  select 'MANAGER'  from dual
)
select col_xml
  from t1
 pivot xml(
   count(*) for col in(select col from t1)
 )
```

XML Result:

```
COL_XML                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<PivotSet><item><column name = "COL">CLERK</column><column name = "COUNT(*)">1</
column></item><item><column name = "COL">MANAGER</column><column name = "COUNT(*
)">1</column></item><item><column name = "COL">SALESMAN</column><column name = "
COUNT(*)">1</column></item></PivotSet>
```

But then, to get the *friendly* representation of data you will have to explicitly extract the values:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 'CLERK'    from dual union all
  3    select 'SALESMAN' from dual union all
  4    select 'MANAGER'  from dual
  5  )
  6  select extractvalue(col_xml,'/PivotSet/item[1]/column[2]') col_1
  7       , extractvalue(col_xml,'/PivotSet/item[2]/column[2]') col_2
  8       , extractvalue(col_xml,'/PivotSet/item[3]/column[2]') col_3
  9    from ( select col_xml
 10             from t1
 11            pivot xml(
 12              count(*) for col in(select col from t1)
 13            )
 14         )
 15  ;
```

Result:

```
COL_1 COL_2 COL_3
-----------------
1     1     1
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15185)

Comment: To add, I wanted the PIVOT for all values in Job, not just for CLERK, SALESMAN and MANAGER...

Comment: @Matkrupp It will give you. Those, listed in the `with` clause just for the sake of demonstration. In this case `select col from t1` query is used in the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT` operator, so it will select all jobs. Then, by issuing `extractvalue()` in the outer query you will decide which job to display.